# Getting only one item to spinner

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(20);
public static final String SharedPref = "MyPreferences";
SharedPreferences settings=null;
Spinner sp;
ArrayAdapter aa;
Intent i;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    settings=getSharedPreferences(SharedPref,0);

    Toast.makeText(this, al.size()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, al);
    sp.setAdapter(aa);

}

public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        int j=0;
        String s =settings.getString("NewTask","");
        try {
            for(j=0;j<20;j++) {
                aa.insert(s,j);
                aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                j++;
                Toast.makeText(this, al.size()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sp.setAdapter(aa);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Array",e+"");
        }
    }



public  void add1(View v)
{
   i = new Intent(this,second.class);
    startActivityForResult(i,1);

}}
```

I need to get items from other Activity.I am moving to second Activity by clicking on add button.There am adding item by edittext and clicking on add button.Then Am getting only one item which i added,but I need all items which added before too.Please help me.My requirement is to use two layouts.(I know Adding item in one layout to spinner ). Size of arraylist is not increasing here.How can I fix my Arraylist size.

Comment: remove `j++;` from `for` loop and call `aa.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `for` loop and also remove `sp.setAdapter(aa)` from `for` loop.

Comment: it is displaying same word for loop no.of times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use startActivityForResult to pass data to activity
>
> For example call startActivityResult from first activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

> And in second activity set data you want to return back like below

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("data",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

> And in your first activity override the onActivityResult() method to get data

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
  data) {
  if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
      {
        String result=data.getStringExtra("data");

     }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
     {

    }

    }
}
```

> Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks.You saved my day.

Comment: @Devika  Your Welcome.